# Mysql: Using str_to_date on a select query returns nothing

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I've following Mysql query:

```
select str_to_date((select distinct cast(substr(tb2.sub1,1,4) AS CHAR) as year from (
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_name,'_',-1) as sub1 from table2) as tb2) , '%Y')
```

And it is correct because mysqlworkbench returns green flag but no output.

Could you help me?

Comment: we don't see the source data, it's hard to judge

Comment: No output? No rows? Means your `SELECT ... from table2` didn't get any results.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
        select str_to_date('2007', '%Y')
```

returns `2007-00-00`. Some MySQL servers are set to disallow [invalid dates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates). Try using

```
        select makedate('2007', 1)
```

instead. That will give you the valid date of `2007-01-01`.

I'm leaving it to you to edit your query to make the change.